# Using ffmpeg to edit images in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, ffmpeg

I have to use ffmpeg library in django.

I have already installed ffmpeg using : pip install ffmpeg-python

The following tasks are to be performed :

1. Take an image as input which in the form of a url (eg : https://imgd.aeplcdn.com/0x0/cw/ec/30146/MercedesBenz-CClass-Right-Rear-Three-Quarter-136699.jpg?wm=0) this is an input image for me
2. Process the image using ffmpeg to :

   a. remove its background

   b. crop 30px from bottom

   c. resize image size to 550 by 300
3. Return the processed image in form of a url.

And the entire code is to be incorporated in working python(django) code.

How to write this piece of code so that the above mentioned functions are performed?

Comment: >a. remove its background - Do you have a mask for this operation? I doubt FFmpeg is smart enough to do it blindly. Others are trivial.

Comment: can you suggest using some libraries to do the same in python?@kesh

Comment: A Google search would be a good place to start. Try "python foreground background segmentation" (It's highly dependent on data, so don't get your hopes too high to find an off-the-shelf solution)

Comment: exactly, most of it's hardcoded

Comment: also, can you please let me know that can urls be used in ffmpeg as input or the image from the url has to be neccesarily downloaded to be processed?

Comment: FFmpeg does support url inputs and outputs. (FFmpeg will download the content on its own, but I'm sure you meant to download them manually)

Comment: no..didn't mean it manually :D 
thanks for the help

Comment: ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -video_size 300x200 -i title="MyWindow"
-filter_complex
"[1]split[m][a];
 [a]format=yuv444p,geq='if(gt(lum(X,Y),0),255,0)',hue=s=0[al];
 [m][al]alphamerge[ovr];
 [0][ovr]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w):main_h-overlay_h[v]"
-map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -r 25 out.mp4 

this works for videos ....can you help me in altering this for images?@kesh